# How to Print the next 20 leap years in Java

Tags: java

I was wondering how to do this because of my assignment.

```
package leapyearsassignment;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class LeapYearsAssignment {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int leapyear;
        int addyear = 4;
        int year;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter a year to print the next 20 years.");
        year = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println( "You are asking for the leap years starting from " + year + ".");

        //for loop here?

    }

}
```

This is what I started with wondering how I would be able to put a 'for loop' to print the next 20 leap years from the year what the user wanted.

EDIT: This is the code I've made before:

```
package leapyearsassignment;

public class LeapYearsAssignment {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int year;

        for ( year = 2016; year <= 2092; year = year +4) {
            System.out.println(year);}

    }

}
```

But instead of 2016, I want the year the user wanted.I'm fairly new to programming and just started a few months ago; September to be exact.

Comment: There is a leap year every 4 years and the maximum "distance" from the input year to the first leap year is 3 years. So how many years do you need to loop over?

Answer (score 1):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the year to check for leap year.");
    int year = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("The next 20 leap years from the given year " + year+ " are: ");
    int count =0;
    while(count != 20){
    year = year+4;
    if((year%400==0) || (year%4==0 && year%100 != 0)){
        System.out.println(year);
    }
    count++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this (accounting correctly for the irregular leap years) is:

- Use a counter variable to count the number of leap years printed
- In a loop:

  - Test if `year` is a leap year

    - If it is a leap year, increment the counter and print the year
    - If the counter reaches 20, break the loop
    - Otherwise, increment year and continue looping

To determine if year is a leap year, you can use this method:

```
public static boolean isLearYear(int year) {
    return year % 4 == 0 && (year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0);
}
```

(This checks that the year is divisible by 4, and accounts for the special exceptions that every 100th year is *not* a leap year, but every 400th is a leap year again).

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int count =  0;

System.out.println("Enter a year");
int current_year = in.nextInt();
System.out.println("The next 20 leap years from "+current_year+" are ");

while(count < 20){
    
    if((current_year % 4 == 0) && (current_year % 100 != 0) || (current_year % 400 == 0))
    {
        System.out.print(current_year+", ");
        count++;
    }
    current_year++;
    
}
```

Comment: This question already contains multiple answers. Can you explain (by editing your answer) where your answer differs from the other answers? Also know that Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.